# Where is the Matarial 3 surface container color in flutter

Tags: flutter, material3

I found that there is no surface container colors in flutter
[image: material 3 color system]

```dart
ColorScheme.fromSeed({
// ...
Color? background,    // In m3, we should use surface as background color
Color? surface,
Color? surfaceVariant,// And use surface container color as the color for a contained area against the surface color
})
```

Comment: Please add a link to the site that you used to create the pallet in the image.
I am using https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom and it currently does not exist there as well.
I think it is missing and we should open an issue for that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is missing, here is an issue for the Flutter team to add support for it.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115912

Feel free to upvote it to increase priority for the issue